# Variable Frequency identifier

Tags: r

I am very new to R and just transferred from Stata. I currently have a very large data set of property transaction data and would like to determine how many times a specific property has been bought/sold over 15 years. I have over 9.5 million transactions but I am confident that there are repeated sales over this period for each property id. The complicated thing is that the property id number looks like this in my data set:

```
{29727138-49F4-4BE3-93EC-09462F52858D}
```

And I would like to see first if this specific id (transaction) occurs again so that secondly, I can build a repeat sales data set with the second transaction price next to the initial sale price. See table below (property unique id on the left as "tid" with corresponding sale price next to it as "sp"). Can anyone please be so kind to give me advice on how to do this? I would really appreciate it as all of my ideas seems to return errors.

Thank you.

```
                   tid                       sp 
{29727138-49F4-4BE3-93EC-09462F52858D}   195000

{9D6C12EB-10AA-405B-8387-BA729A8E6FF3}   635000

{54FE95DD-9D52-482F-A25A-46DFE2E84238}   107000

{6145CF24-9961-49B7-9298-812E9EA2E806}   140000
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that you currently have an R dataframe named 'dat' with these columns, this will produce a list of properties which have sold more than once:

```
 proptbl <- table(dat$tid)
 multsales <- names(proptbl)[proptbl > 1]
```

Those values for dat$tid are probably factors if you just used the defaults for the read.* function at the time of input, but that should not make a difference in this case. If you wanted to reduce the dataset to more manageable proportions where you were only looking at the subset with multiple sales, you could do this:

```
smldat <- dat[ dat$tid %in% multsales , ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it worked! Initially I tried to create a frequency table to first identify if duplicates existed, but given the size of the data set, it returned errors due to max memory allocation. Thank you once again.